# Метод или операция не реализована

Tags: c#

Что значит "Метод или операция не реализована"? У меня в этом коде ошибка:

```
IEnumerable<Game> IGameRepository.Games
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: А что, по-вашему, делает конструкция `throw new NotImplementedException()`?

Comment: ничего не делает.

Comment: "Метод или операция не реализована" означает, что метод или операция не реализованы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы реализовали код, который при вызове бросает ошибку об отсутствии реализации метода. Он бросает исключение NotImplementedException, а оно выбрасывается, когда запрошенный метод или операция не реализованы.

Подозреваю, что это автоматически с генерированная заглушка. Вписывайте туда то, что Вы хотите от реализации метода.

Про NotImplementedException читайте подробно [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.notimplementedexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: спасибо @Dejsving.